# Ubuntu core 16, Raspberry Pi 3, bluetooth vs. apparmor

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, apparmor

I am having trouble seeing any Bluetooth controllers on my Rasberry Pi 3 running Core 16.

Installed snaps:

```
Name             Version       Rev  Developer  Notes
bluez            5.37-2        12   canonical  -
core             16.04.1       645  canonical  -
docker           1.11.2-9      59   canonical  -
hello            2.10          24   canonical  -
network-manager  1.2.2-10      72   canonical  -
pi2-kernel       4.4.0-1030-3  22   canonical  -
pi3              16.04-0.5     6    canonical  -
snapweb          0.21.2        25   canonical  -
wifi-ap          9             28   canonical  -
wireless-tools   2             9    canonical  -
```

Bluetooth control command output:

```
sudo bluez.bluetoothctl -a 
Agent registered 
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]#
```

Get nothing.  No controllers found or listed.

Looking in the logs for anything Bluetooth related, it seems like the hardware is there, but apparmor might be blocking the snap.

```
sudo grep -i tooth /var/log/syslog 


Dec 14 15:47:58 localhost kernel: [149278.605497] audit: type=1400 audit(1481730478.267:95): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" pid=5827 comm="bluetoothctl" capability=1  capname="dac_override"
Dec 14 15:47:58 localhost kernel: [149278.605549] audit: type=1400 audit(1481730478.267:96): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" pid=5827 comm="bluetoothctl" capability=2  capname="dac_read_search"
Nov  2 14:54:16 localhost kernel: [   21.892285] audit: type=1400 audit(1478098451.155:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluez.bluetoothctl" pid=1100 comm="apparmor_parser"
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.142418] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.142559] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.142587] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.142607] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.142648] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost bluetoothd[1319]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost bluetoothd[1319]: Starting SDP server
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.256492] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.256516] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost kernel: [   44.256542] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Dec 14 16:11:39 localhost bluetoothd[1319]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
```

This is where I get a bit lost, and am wondering what the next step in troubleshooting this problem would be; how should I proceed?

Comment: `snap connect` might be needed....